# Chromatic Number Inequality

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I have come across this inequality, and was hoping someone could help explain to me why it holds. It is that $$e(G)\geq\begin{pmatrix} \chi(G) \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

I can't intuitively see how it holds, and I'm not sure where to begin with proving it.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There must be at least one edge between every two color classes, or else you could merge them.

Comment: So I wonder how you can "intuitively see" how it holds

Comment: Since a coloring of $G$ with $n$ colors corresponds to a graph homomorphism to the complete Graph $K_n$, which has $n\choose{2}$ edges, at least the appearance of ${\chi(G)}\choose{2}$ becomes intuitively clear. The inequality then says that this particular homomorphism must be surjective on edges.